# Microsoft Store - Error 0x80073CFE and other strange things

Tags: windows-10, powershell, microsoft-store

I've some problem with Microsoft Store on Windows 10, version 1909 (built SO 18363.959). In Settings, App...it doesn't appears, but, if I search it, it appears but doesn't open.

To fix the problem I run the command (as suggested [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMDxX0X1Gh8)):

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

in the powershell (launched as admin). The results was a lot of 0x80073CFE errors, and now I am not able to open Settings (when I click on it, it becomes as in the below figure).

[image]

Before the above solution I tried also [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eq9trFpHtmg) solutions, but without any success.

Could you suggest me a way to fix these problems without losing the data please?

---

EDIT: I'd like to preserve the installed softwares as well.

Also the windows icons (battery, volume, ecc) in the toolbar do not work.

---

EDIT2: the command

```
DISM /online /Cleanup-Image / ScanHealth
```

produces the following error (the strange thing is that now the weather app works):

Error: 87

Management and maintenance of distribution images: impossible to recognize
the command line option "".
For more information, see the Help through the DISM.exe /? Command.

The Image Management and Maintenance log file
distribution is available at C: \ WINDOWS \ Logs \ DISM \ dism.log

---

EDIT3: after the running of the command sfc /scannow, the output is: Windows Resource Protection: No integrity violations found.

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run first dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then second SFC /SCANNOW  When done, close everything and see if Store is now in Settings, Apps. Then repair it from there.

Comment: You ran a destructive command.  Performing an in-place repair to the same version is the best solution

Comment: Hello @John I tried your commands, the results in the cmd are ok, but settings (and other stuff) do not work as before

Answer (score 0):

To restore the correct state of Windows, there are two solutions:

- If you have System Restore enabled (recommended), rollback to a previous
  restore point.
- [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Hi @harrymc thank you for your solution. I edited my request: I need to preserve data and installed softwares as well.

Comment: Both solutions will do that.

Comment: Hi @harrymc I did the in-place update. Now I can open settings, windows icons, but Microsoft Store doesn't appear in the list of installed softwares. If I search it and click on it, it doesn't open. Morover I can't open email windows app, calendar windows app, weather windows app. Could you suggest me a way to fix these problems please?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1367964/8672). Do NOT use any other link from that post.

Comment: in Apps & features there isn't microsoft store

Comment: Try *Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Store Apps > Run the troubleshooter*.

Comment: the result is: impossible to identify the problem

Comment: What have you done to cause such a problem?

Comment: this is a very good question. At the beginning my intention was to uninstall Microsoft Store because it didn't allow me to download apps (it showed always an error message). The problem is that I don't remember how I tried to uninstall it. Maybe I followed this tutorial (I'm not sure): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWaDfHwdwQM

Comment: I know this command (mentioned in your post) and it should not have caused such a problem. Perhaps there was already some corruption in Windows when you ran it. Question: Did you do this operation recently? In any case try another one: In the Start menu, type `wsreset` and select 'Run as Administrator'. Let it run alone on the computer, and if successful then the Microsoft Store app will be launched automatically.

Comment: I don't remember what I did:( The result of wsreset is: you'll need a new app to open this...so it didn't work

Comment: Was this done recently enough to use System Restore to rollback Windows to before you did it (if it's enabled)?

Comment: I think that I cannot use System Restore because I did the mess more than a month ago; so I prefer to avoid System Restore

Comment: One more: In an elevated CMD, run the two commands `DISM /online /Cleanup-Image / ScanHealth` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. Follow with [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Finally reboot.

Comment: could I skip the link you posted?

Comment: Just use the command `sfc /scannow`, the link is for more information only.

Comment: If DISM is gone then Windows is totally loused up. Try `sfc /scannow` as last action. Otherwise, System Restore is the last possibility before a Reset (which is similar to clean install). See Microsoft's [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options). You don't have too many options left.

Comment: No, SFC didn't find what the problem is. So, sorry, none of the troubleshooting tools worked for you, so you will need to do stronger operations. Take good backups, up to and including an image backup of the system disk, just in case.

Comment: ok, thank you very much @harrymc I think that I'll avoid to use MS store and its apps

Comment: Your choice of course. Just keep in mind that System Restore rollabck becomes impossible as time moves on.

Comment: MS store has never worked on my PC; I could not install apps also before the above problem

Comment: The problem then dates from too long ago to be solved by anything else than a clean install. If the computer otherwise works well for you, then it can stay this way.